# I cannot re install backpack/pro for Laravel. Error github.com/Laravel-Backpack/PRO.git not found

Tags: laravel, composer-php, laravel-backpack-5

when I run composer update ...

Failed to execute git clone --mirror -- https://ghp...VWs:x-oauth-basic@github.com/Laravel-Backpac
k/PRO.git "C:/Users/Andre NENY/AppData/Local/Composer/vcs/git-github.com-Laravel-Backpack-PRO.git/
"

Cloning into bare repository 'C:/Users/Andre NENY/AppData/Local/Composer/vcs/git-github.com-Larave
l-Backpack-PRO.git'...
remote: Repository not found.
fatal: repository 'https://github.com/Laravel-Backpack/PRO.git/' not found

I try also to run composer require backpack/pro -W and I obtain:

Root composer.json requires backpack/pro ^1.6 -> satisfiable by backpack/pro[1.6.0, ..., 1.6.4].
- backpack/pro[1.6.0, ..., 1.6.4] require backpack/crud ^5.4.9 -> found backpack/crud[5.4.9, ..., 5.6.0] but it conflicts with your root composer.json require (5.1.2).

You can also try re-running composer require with an explicit version constraint, e.g. "composer require backpack/pro:*" to figure out if any version is installable, or "composer require backpack/pro:^2.1" if you know which you need.

Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json and ./composer.lock to their original content.

Comment: `backpack/crud` in v5.1.2 is pretty outdated (nearly a year old), and not compatible with the package you want to install. Why not update it?